# Как вывести url изображения из sqlite базы?

Tags: php, sqlite

Получаю данные о товаре из базы sqlite с помощью следующего кода:

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT * from items WHERE item_id=$click_id LIMIT 1");

while ($item_id = $results->fetchArray()) 
{ 

//echo ($item_id['title'].$item_id['description']." (id записи:".$item_id['id'].")<br />"); 

echo '<strong><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="https://site.ru/' .$item_id['id']. '">' .$item_id['title']. '</a></strong><br /><br />';
echo $item_id['description']."<br /><br />";
echo $item_id['wareUrl']."<br /><br />";
echo $item_id['price']."<br /><br />";
echo $item_id['id']."<br />"; 

echo $item_id['images']."<br />";
echo $item_id['images']['original']."<br /><br />";

}
```

`echo $item_id['images'];` выводит список допустимых избражений, следующего вида
 {"original":"images/a0bbdf735e8d5af986ab020a0b4eaccf.png","medium":null,"small":"images/a0bbdf735e8d5af986ab020a0b4eaccf-small.png"}

Пытаюсь вывести оригинальное избражение так

`echo $item_id['images']['original'];` но получаю сообщение об ошибке:

Warning: Illegal string offset 'original' in {

Хочу вывести самое мальнькое из доступных изображений так

`echo $item_id['images']['small'] ? $item_id['images']['small'] : ($item_id['images']['medium'] ? $item_id['images']['medium'] : $item_id['images']['original']);` но получаю сообщение об ошибке:

Warning: Illegal string offset 'small' in {

Как правильно получить url нужного изображения?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас в базе хранится json, выполните json_decode($item_id['images']) для его преобразования в объект

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Большое спасибо!